# Editing window.location.hash will cause the query string to be removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

I have the following string:

```
http://example.com/?phrase=samplePhrase
```

And when I click on a certain element the URL receives a hash-edit like this:

```
#show/item
```

Using this javascript code:

```
window.location.hash =  "/" + "show" + "/" + "item";
```

But I want just this hash-edit to append to whatever current URL is. So to have:

```
http://example.com/?phrase=samplePhrase#show/item
```

But it first remove what ever query string is and then makes url like this:

```
http://example.com/#/show/item
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get the params out of the URL, you should be able to do something like this:

```
var params = window.location.search;
window.location.hash =  params + "#" + "show" + "/" + "item";
```